# Silverlight HTTP POST

Tags: silverlight

I am just trying to perform an http post on http://www.test.com/test.asp?test1=3.  Here is the code I have been trying to use:

```
    private void pif_test_conn()
    {


        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.test.com/test.asp?test1=3", UriKind.Absolute);



        if (httpResult == true)
        {


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
           request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request); 

        }



        return ;
    }


   private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;


        HttpWebResponse response =  (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        using (StreamReader streamReader1 =  new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();

             MessageBox.Show("Using HttpWebRequest: " + resultString, "Found", MessageBoxButton.OK);             
        }

    }
```

When I execute this code my program triggers the Application_UnhandledException event.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: no post data? do mean to POST or GET

Comment: {System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only send HTTP requests to the domain that your app comes from.

This restriction prevents [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to post to another host? That behavior could lead to XSS security problems, so that isnt available.

```
string responseValue = "";
AutoResetEvent syncRequest = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Uri address = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "/sample.aspx");

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);
request.Method = "POST";
request.BeginGetRequestStream(getRequestResult =>
{
    // Send packet data
    using (Stream post = request.EndGetRequestStream(getRequestResult))
    {
        post.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        post.Close();
    }

    // wait for server response
    request.BeginGetResponse(getResponseResult =>
    {
        WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(getResponseResult);
        responseValue=new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        syncRequest.Set();

    }, null);

}, null);

syncRequest.WaitOne();

MessageBox.Show(
    "Using WebRequest: " + responseValue, 
    "Found", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

HTH

Comment: Your format for handling the triple async of a silverlight post is awesome.  This is so much more compact than creating multiple handler functions.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to [Rubens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528872/silverlight-http-post/1528941#1528941),

If you leave in the `SyncRequest.WaitOne()` call, the call deadlocks, at least in Silverlight 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an HTTP POST, you need to write the POST data to the request by calling the [`BeginGetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream%28VS.95%29.aspx) method.

This is probably why you're getting an exception; please tell us what exception you're geting for a more specific answer.

Comment: System.Security.SecurityException